# How to setup touchpad in from the cli

Tags: command-line, touchpad

I have a Lenovo t540p laptop and its touchpad acts like a physical left button, the touchpad has no left or right buttons, so I need to make a fixed bottom area of the laptop left and right buttons. Also, I need to leave the rest of the touchpad unresponsive to the touch.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a file called  `70-synaptics.conf` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` and put the following content in it:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        # Enable clickpad/multitouch support
        Option "ClickPad" "true"
        # Middle-button emulation is not supported
        Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
        # Define right soft button at the bottom
        Option "SoftButtonAreas"  "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Hope this helps.